# Is there a way to differentiate website hosts with PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a free webhost to test out a website as I code it. Someone I know on steam has just bought a VPS subscription, and also offered to host the site (as a learning experience for him). I wouldn't want to fully move across as he's only got the basics set up, so all the bits like phpmyadmin aren't installed.

I was just thinking that since I could keep the same site synced up with both the free host and his server without any effort, is there some function I could use to get a unique ID for the website host, so that I could supply different database details for each one?

My idea is around the lines of this:

```
$db_login => array(
    12345 => array(user, pass),
    56789 => array(user2, pass2)
);

$db_details = $db_login[$_SERVER['websitehost']];
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'buddyvps.example.com') { do stuff for vps } else { do stuff for freehost }`

Comment: I'd like it to be not reliant on the URL if possible though, since the free webhost is linked to the domain I bought and I may end up changing it eventually. I'm wondering if there's something more in the background, so if I have "www.mysite.com", running the code would find "host:server.000webhost.com" or something

Comment: that isn't the url. that's the server's name within the apache config.

Comment: @Peter `SERVER_NAME` is exactly for that purpose. You're confusing it with `HTTP_HOST`

Comment: server_name != site_name. one single server can host MULTIPLE sites. which is why there's http_host. that identifies a specific website hosted by the server.

Comment: I've just tried both `SERVER_NAME` and `HTTP_HOST`, both return as `mysite.com`, no mention of 000webhost :P

Comment: I just printed all the values and it turns out `$_SERVER[SERVER_ADMIN]` is `admin@000webhost.com`, is this value likely to be unique for each host?

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` will give the IP of the server. You can see a list of server values here, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. Note `There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.`

Comment: Thanks, works with both hosts so exactly what I was after assuming they don't change IP addresses :)

Comment: You could put it into a switch and make the default `Unknown Server IP, contact Peter (he'll know what to do)!`